# How turn off airplane mode?

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, vaio, sony

I have a problem getting the WIFI to work in Ubuntu 20.04. In short i can not use WIFI, cause of airplane on. I can not turn off airplane mode. My laptop: Sony VAIO VGN-FW560F.
Output of: `sudo rfkill unblock all` and `sudo rfkill list` -

```
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: `Hard blocked: yes` that means your *hardware* switch is disabling WiFi. On many laptops, it's a keyboard combination triggering a BIOS function instead of a separate switch. Since it's BIOS, Ubuntu cannot override or control it. Look at your keyboard for a WiFi icon.

Comment: RTFM: User Guide, page 12.

Comment: @FedKad please stays nice :) especially to new user. Fn+F9 toggles wifi it seems.

Comment: @Rinzwind Read The Fine Manual is polite. What were you thinking?

Answer (score 1):

On page 12 of “**Sony VGN-FW Series User Guide**” (see:
https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/res/manuals/W001/W0011700M.pdf) it is clearly shown that the “WIRELESS switch [9]” is on the front side of the computer. Please, make sure it is ON, i.e. at right position.

[image: page 12 a] . [image: page 12 b]

I know from experience that, as time passes, this switch may become loose and may not work properly.

Note also that there is no <kbd>Fn</kbd> (soft) keyboard combination to toggle WiFi as in other brand of computers.